# Why does this Haskell program leak space when compiled with optimizations?

Tags: haskell, optimization, memory-leaks, ghc

Consider the following toy program that computes all combinations of character substitutions in a word, of the kind often used in passwords.

```
import Data.Char (isLower, toUpper)

variants :: String -> [String]
variants "" = [""]
variants (c:s) = [c':s' | c' <- subst c, s' <- variants s]
  where subst 'a' = "aA@"
        subst 'e' = "eE3"
        subst 'i' = "iI1"
        subst 'l' = "lL1"
        subst 'o' = "oO0"
        subst 's' = "sS$5"
        subst 'z' = "zZ2"
        subst x | isLower x = [x, toUpper x]
        subst x = [x]

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn $ show $ length $ variants "redistributables"
```

I compile it with and without optimizations:

```
$ ghc -fforce-recomp -Wall Test.hs -o test0
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Test.hs, Test.o )
Linking test0 ...

$ ghc -fforce-recomp -O -Wall Test.hs -o test1
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Test.hs, Test.o )
Linking test1 ...
```

Now `test0` and `test1` produce the same output, but `test1` uses much more memory and spends most of its time in garbage collection:

```
$ ./test0 +RTS -s 2>&1 | grep total
               2 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)
  Productivity  93.2% of total user, 93.3% of total elapsed

$ ./test1 +RTS -s 2>&1 | grep total
             188 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)
  Productivity  15.0% of total user, 15.0% of total elapsed
```

Why?

I’m using GHC 7.4.1; I should probably use a newer compiler, but this is what I have handy at the moment, and the fault probably lies with me anyway.

Comment: 7.4 is pretty ancient at this point, at least use 7.8 if not 7.10.  To answer this you're probably going to have to pass `-ddump-simpl` to get the core output, then go through that to figure out exactly what the difference is.

Comment: @bheklilr Done that. Of course the generated Core is very different, but it’s really hard for a Haskell novice to untangle and so far I haven’t succeeded.

Comment: and what happens with -O2 flag?

Comment: @WillNess Same as with `-O`.

Comment: would running  `foldr (\x->(* length (subst x))) 1 "redistributables"` be satisfactory?

Comment: @WillNess Thanks for the fold suggestion, but I’m not solving an actual problem here, I’m just playing with the language/runtime and trying to get a sense of what’s going on, so I’d like to find the cause.

Comment: @WillNess `-fno-full-laziness` does not make a difference.

Comment: I get very similar results on 7.10.1.

Comment: `variants (c:cs) = variants cs >>= \s-> map (:s) (subst c)` ? `mapM subst` ?

Comment: It's hard to believe it's not full laziness, but there's also a difference in list comprehension desugaring depending on whether rules are enabled.

Comment: @WillNess The former does the trick, the latter doesn’t.

Comment: @WillNess @dfeuer Oops, it turns out the relative order of `-O`  and `-fno-full-laziness` matters. When I give `-O -fno-full-laziness`, total memory usage drops back to 2M. Productivity is still only 46% though.

Comment: the trick is to cause the recomputation of suffixes, instead of their retention in memory. it's like with the `powerset (x:xs) = map (x:) (powerset xs) ++ powerset xs` definition, adding `where` clause is harmful. (or is it `powerset (x:xs) = powerset xs ++ map (x:) (powerset xs) ` ?)

Comment: @WillNess Thank you. I can see how full laziness causes this problem. I can now see it in the Core, too. If you post an answer, I will accept. However, with `-fno-full-laziness` I still have the problem of productivity: the optimized version is 2.7 times slower, with GC copying 70 times more bytes. Would be great if you could comment on that as well. Or should I post it as a separate question?

Comment: What do the total allocation numbers look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want

```
variants (c:s) = [c':s' | c' <- subst c, s' <- variants s]
```

to be compiled into an outer loop and an inner loop. But GHC sees that the inner loop does not depend in any way on the outer "loop counter". Therefore, the full laziness transformation lifts the inner loop out of the outer loop. One fairly effective trick is to hide the fact that the inner loop is independent. This is done by splitting the inner loop off into a separate function taking a dummy argument, and hiding the dumminess by marking the function as `NOINLINE`. Then you can call the function with the outer loop counter, and GHC will generally refrain from messing with you.

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to cause the recomputation of suffixes, instead of their retention in memory. It's like with the

```
powerset (x:xs) = map (x:) (powerset xs) ++ powerset xs
```

definition, where adding the `where` clause is harmful (or is it `powerset (x:xs) = powerset xs ++ map (x:) (powerset xs)` ...?).

In your case, the code to try is `mapM subst`, or

```
variants (c:cs) = variants cs >>= \s-> map (:s) (subst c)
```

You can see that the latter works in the "opposite direction" from your list comprehension code, so maybe just

```
variants (c:s) = [c':s' | s' <- variants s, c' <- subst c]
```

will work, too.

All these are equivalent, so it's a compiler thing. Hopefully someone can provide more specifics about that.

Comment: Indeed, swapping `c' <- subst c` with `s' <- variants s` produces (under `-O2`) the best result for me: constant space and fast.